# Advanced Search Function with PHP

Tags: php, forms, loops, if-statement, advanced-search

currently I have a form that allows users to fill in 3 input fields. 3 of them are text fields (title, author and ISBN) and 1 of it is a select option (categories).

What I would like to achieve is to allow users to fill in any number of the 4 fields, and return the respected values. This means that if users fills in 2 input fields, there will be 2 conditions to check in the backend. 3 inputs filled means 3 conditions.

What I have currenly is this (an example, not the actual code itself):

```
    if($title == $allMyArray["title"]){
        array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    }else if($author == $allMyArray["author"]){
        array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    }else if($ISBN == $allMyArray["ISBN"]){
        array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    }else if($categoreis== $allMyArray["categories"]){
        array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    }else{
        echo "nothing";
    }
```

This set of code works when I only fill in one specific field. For example if I fill in only the author input, and leave the other 3 options blank, I will be returned wwith the values I want. However, if I attempt to fill in 2 or more fields at once, the returned value is incorrect.

So how else can I come up with an if else statement that will check which fields are filled, and set the conditions correctly based on the inputted fields?

Thank you all for your help in advanced! Much appreciated! :)

Comment: That doesn't making any sense to run the same command in each and every condition. BTW, what "the returned value is incorrect." means? Can you share the returned value in the question please?

Comment: Use 4 `if`s, without `else`

Comment: My mistake, @Ofir Baruch. It does make sense because this function is actually under another function. So what this whole thing does is first, it will retrieve all the records in the database. Then it will loop through every record, and see if it matches. If it matches, it will push the data into a resultArray, which I will be using for sessions afterwards.

Hence, each conditions that are met will result in data being push into the resultArray.

Comment: Hi, @u_mulder, I have just attempted to do so but there seem to be duplicates in the results.

Answer (score 1):

Changing to below code will work. The problem is when you use ELSE you are limiting your conditional statements to one result only.

Optionally, you can use switch/case statement if you find IF dirty.

But it may produce duplicates, so you need to work this out. (i dont know your code, it is just an assumption)

```
$atLeast1Result = false;
if($title == $allMyArray["title"]){
    array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    $atLeast1Result = true;
}
if($author == $allMyArray["author"]){
    array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    $atLeast1Result = true;
} 
if($ISBN == $allMyArray["ISBN"]){
    array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    $atLeast1Result = true;
}
if($categoreis== $allMyArray["categories"]){
    array_push($returningResult, $allMyArray);
    $atLeast1Result = true;
}
if(!$atLeast1Result ) {
    echo "nothing";
} else {
    $returningResult = array_unique($returningResult); // this might now work on all versions, as i dont know what this array is.
}
```

Comment: yup, I have attempted this, but Im running into duplicates as we speak

Comment: I updated the code to remove duplicates ... but this will not work on all scenarios (i don tknow what $allMyArray is). have a try and let us know if it worked.

Comment: ahhh I've tested it on my own, but I still have some errors. I should try to debug it first, then I'll get back to you. Thanks for your help!